# Cannot find file in Node even though it has correct path

Tags: node.js, fs

After executing this code:

```
const filename = "../../.dburl"
const url = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')
```

I recieve the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../.dburl'
```

What I know so far:

1) The filepath is correct.

2) My application has permission to read the file.

3) .dburl is not read even when stored in the same directory as the application.

Any help is much appreciated ... Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the path to `.dburl` is relative to where you're running your script from? The current working directory the path is relative to is not the location of the script making the `readFileSync` call.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the module-level variable `__dirname` to get the directory that contains the current script.  Then you can use `path.resolve()` to use relative paths.

```
console.log('Path of file in parent dir:', require('path').resolve(__dirname, '../app.js'));
```

Answer (score 10):

### READING FILE ON SAME LEVEL

[image]

```
 //the server object listens on port 8080
    const PORT = 8080;
    var http = require("http");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var path = require("path");

    //create a server object:
    http
      .createServer((req, res) => {
        console.log("READING FILE: ", path.resolve(__dirname, "input.txt"));

        fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "input.txt"), (err, data) => {
          //error handling
          if (err) return console.error(err);

          //return file content
          console.log("FILE CONTENT: " + data.toString());
          res.write(data.toString());
          res.end();
          console.log("READ COMPLETED");
        });
      })
      .listen(PORT);
```

### READING FILE ON OTHER LEVEL:

[image]

```
//the server object listens on port 8080
const PORT = 8080;
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

//create a server object:
http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("READING FILE: ", path.resolve(__dirname, "./mock/input.txt"));

    fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./mock/input.txt"), (err, data) => {
      //error handling
      if (err) return console.error(err);

      //return file content
      console.log("FILE CONTENT: " + data.toString());
      res.write(data.toString());
      res.end();
      console.log("READ COMPLETED");
    });
  })
  .listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're confusing the current working directory of your script for the location of your script. It's hard to say without knowing the structure of your project and where you're calling the script from.

Assuming your shell's working directory is `/`, `.dburl` is at `/.dburl` and your script is located at `/foo/bar/script.js`. If you run `node foo/bar/script`, you could read `.dburl` with `readFileSync('./dburl')`. However if you run `cd foo/bar; node ./script`, you would need to read `.dburl` with `readFileSync('../../.dburl')`.

This is because the working directory of your script is equal to the working directory of the shell you launched it in.

Comment: So relative filepaths are relative to the working directory of the shell and not to the location of the script?

Comment: Atleast in the context of node?

Comment: @srpalo Yes. Try adding `console.log(process.cwd())` to your script and it will print the directory all of your fs paths are relative to. `require` calls are relative to the script's path though.

Comment: The output of process.cwd() is the filepath of where the script is located. If that's true, then shouldn't ../../.dburl be correct since I created it relative to the scripts location?

Comment: Before running your script, run `ls ../../.dburl`. If it says "No such file or directory", your script won't be able to find it.

Comment: The output of `ls ../../.dburl` is the filepath included in the command.

Comment: So if it can access the file, then why is it not able to?

Comment: I'm not sure. I assumed it was a path issue. Try replacing `../../.dburl` with the absolute path to `.dburl`. If that works, your relative path is wrong; otherwise, something else is going on.